# WMI Associators of DiskDrive Where Result Class is MSStorageDriver

Tags: wmi, wql

Trying to link DiskDrives found in `Win32_DiskDrive` with the data in `MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData`.

I've tried the following WQL statement, but it returned nothing each time. (I know that there is relevant data in the MSStorageDrive class)

`ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=[value]} WHERE RESULTCLASS = MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData`

Any ideas to match the data up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was this:

`SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData WHERE InstanceName='[PNPDeviceID]'`

Just make sure to double-escape any backslashses. So if the PNPDeviceID as found in Win32_DiskDrive was

`IDE\DISKHITACHI_HDT725050VLA360_________________V56OA7EA\5&276E2DE5&0&1.0.0`

what would be returned by getting the value will be

`IDE\\DISKHITACHI_HDT725050VLA360_________________V56OA7EA\\5&276E2DE5&0&1.0.0`

but what you need to send in the WHERE clause is

`IDE\\\\DISKHITACHI_HDT725050VLA360_________________V56OA7EA\\\\5&276E2DE5&0&1.0.0`

Silly, isn't it?

Oh, and from what I've gathered, you also need _0 on the end of the Device ID, so all together, you would send:

`SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData WHERE InstanceName='IDE\\\\DISKHITACHI_HDT725050VLA360_________________V56OA7EA\\\\5&276E2DE5&0&1.0.0_0'`